# How to remove attributes from angular ReactiveForm without changing the original one?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have an angular reactive form made by form array like below and store it on myForm variable.

```
 this.myForm= this.fb.group({
          elements: this.fb.array(
            this.formElements.map((e, i) => {
              return this.fb.group({
                Active:e.Active,
                Id:e.Id,
                Name:e.Name
              })
            })
          ),
        })
```

After I edit this form,I need to send it to `API` but there is `name` attribute which is not necessary therefore should be removed from `params` object.

```
save()
{
    const formValue=[...this.myForm.value.elements];
    formValue.forEach(e=>{delete e.Name;});
    const params={"dataObject":formValue}
}
```

Not to change original form I decided to make hardcopy of formValue but didnt change anything.How can I keep original form and send it to API with removed name attributes?

**EDIT**

While trying different methods this one solved the problem.

```
const formValue=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.myForm.value.elements));
```

Is there another better way instead of JSON stringifying and parsing?

Comment: const formValue = Object.assign({}, this.myForm.value. elements)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
const params = {
  "dataObject": formValue.map(({ Name, ...e }) => ({ ...e }));
}
```